# Nodejs indexOf specific number

Tags: javascript, indexof

This code:

```
var t = "test 55";
t.indexOf("5") !== -1
```

Output true,

But this code:

```
var t = "test 55";
t.indexOf("5") !== -1
```

Also output true,

How do i make it only output true, when its the exact same number, so like this:

```
var t = "test 55";
t.indexOf("5") !== -1
```

Output: false,

```
var t = "test 5";
t.indexOf("5") !== -1
```

Output true.

---

Comment: indexOf will get the first index of a string or array that matches the given input. Can you give more context on your use case. Because you can use strict equality to compare for exact numbers/strings. eg. "5" === "5" which would return true, but false on "55" === "5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value in double or single quotes is treated by JavaScript as String type. Therefore what indexOf is actually doing is looking for a substring ("5") inside of string ("55").

I'm not sure why you're trying to use indexOf to compare the numbers, can't you just use:

```
var t = "55";
t == 5 //false
t == "55" // true
t == "5" // false
```

Note that I used == and not ===. Using == will convert values to the same types (in case of t = "55" to string) and compare them.

**EDIT**

Since op clarified that t value contains both numbers and letters, then in order to perform comparison, additional logic is needed.

1. Extract number from string.
2. Compare it with a provided number.

You can achieve it by using a function:

```
function compare(number, stringWithNumber) {
  // slice string with number to get a string starting with a number
  const stringStartingWithNumber = stringWithNumber.slice(stringWithNumber.search(/\d/));
  return parseFloat(stringStartingWithNumber) == number; // parseFloat removes the rest of the string and parses found number as float
}
```

Then:

```
compare("5", "55") // false
compare("5", "5") // true
compare("5", "sometext 55") // false
compare("5", "sometext 5") // true
```

Please note that the function will compare the provided number only with the first number it finds in the stringWithNumber argument.

Comment: This was just an example, the actual t value contains letters aswell
t1 = "test 5"
t2 = "test 55"
t3 = "test 5.5"

Answer (score 0):

`.indexOf()` is not fit to do what you want. You can use `.search()` (the more so as the original version of your question had the tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)).
You didn't explicitly indicate what `5.5` should yield, so I'll give two expressions - the first, simpler `/\b5\b/` matches it, and the second, more complicated `/(^|[^.])\b5\b(?!\.)/` doesn't. The exclusion of a decimal point got asymmetric before vs. after the `5` because I forwent using a lookbehind assertion, which is only supported from ECMAScript 2018 onwards.

```js
t = ["5", "test 5", "test 55", "test 5.5"]
console.log('with regex '+/\b5\b/)
for (i in t)
  console.log(t[i], t[i].search(/\b5\b/) !== -1)
console.log('with regex '+/(^|[^.])\b5\b(?!\.)/)
for (i in t)
  console.log(t[i], t[i].search(/(^|[^.])\b5\b(?!\.)/) !== -1)
```